# Code Coverage not Displaying in Developer Console

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Before '14 release there was a invaluable feature in salesforce to check the covered/uncovered code segments of a particular class or trigger. They were clearly showed with pink and red color so that developers can easily manage the code coverage. But recently forums say it has been moved into developer console. But I can't find that feature even in the console. Please help if anyone know the job.

Comment: Take a look at this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/code-coverage-on-dev-console. Possible duplicate

Comment: Though that post almost similar to this, the answer provided there is not working