# Developer Console not showing covered lines by test method

Tags: developer-console, code-coverage

I want to know the lines of my apex class which are not covered by the test classes. I know its only possible in developer console now. But seems to be some issue there again.

I ran all tests in developer console. And I opened the controller in the console that I want the coverage for.  But it shows no coverage. When I checked in the browser though for this class, it shows 80%. But here it shows nothing, doesn't show which line are convered and not.

The dropdown in the image below should ideally show me the list of all test classes and All classes. but it itsn't. What is the problem? Please let me know. Or any other alternatives please?

Thanks

[image: developer console]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code coverage on dev console](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/code-coverage-on-dev-console). Try the link

Comment: hmm. BruceLee does appear to have the code coverage drop down in their developer console though, so not sure if this is a dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of the Latest release from salesforce side. CS16 sandboxes all have the same problem. I tried CS15 sandbox, and it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that in latest Winter 2016 upgrade a bug was introduced where code coverage line highlights are missing from the Salesforce Developer Console

You can get them back by selecting the 'Test > Always Run Asynchronously' checkbox and re-running your test.

[image: salesforce-code-coverage-highlight-missing-fix]

Comment: Yea, this is an existing bug, not just with 2016 upgrade.